# Tolerance analysis Program in c

Tags: c

I've created the first part of a tolerance analysis program. I now need to make a function that allows me to adjust the parts or tolerances of the file I have opened to get the specified gap and tolerance. I can't figure this out, I could use some help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>



float toleracning(int size, float nominal[],float tollerance[],int sign[],char VorF[],float Spec_Minnimum,float Spec_Maximum);
int input(float nominal[],float tollerance[],int sign[],char VorF[],float* p_Spec_Minnimum,float* p_Spec_Maximum);
void output(int size, float nominal[],float tollerance[],int sign[],char VorF[],float Spec_Minnimum,float Spec_Maximum);
float toleranceadjust(int size, float nominal[],float tollerance[], int sign[], char VorF[]);

int main(void){

float nominal[10], tollerance[10];
int sign[10];
char VorF[10];
float Spec_Minnimum, Spec_Maximum;

int size = 0;
size = input( nominal, tollerance, sign, VorF, &Spec_Minnimum, &Spec_Maximum);
output( size, nominal, tollerance, sign, VorF, Spec_Minnimum, Spec_Maximum);
toleracning(size, nominal, tollerance, sign, VorF, Spec_Minnimum, Spec_Maximum);
toleranceadjust(size,nominal, tollerance,sign,VorF);

return 0;
}

int input(float nominal[],float tollerance[],int sign[],char VorF[],float* p_Spec_Minnimum,float* p_Spec_Maximum)
{
int status = 0, i;
FILE *FTIN;
FTIN = fopen ("tin.txt", "r");

if (FTIN == NULL){
    printf("ERROR\n");
    return (-1);
}

else{
    for (i=0; status != EOF && i < 100; ){
        status = fscanf(FTIN,"PART,%f,%d,%f,%c\n", &nominal[i], &sign[i], &tollerance[i], &VorF[i]);
        if(status == 4)
        {
            i++;
        }
        status = fscanf(FTIN, "GAP,%f,%f\n", p_Spec_Minnimum, p_Spec_Maximum);  //scans for a gap

        }
    fclose(FTIN);
    return i;
    }
}

void output(int size, float nominal[],float tollerance[],int sign[],char VorF[],float Spec_Minnimum,float Spec_Maximum)
{
   int i;
for (i=0; i < size; i++)
{
      printf("PART,%.3f,%d,%.3f,%c\n", nominal[i], sign[i], tollerance[i], VorF[i]);
}
printf("GAP,%.3f,%.3f\n", Spec_Minnimum, Spec_Maximum);
}

float toleracning(int size, float nominal[],float tollerance[],int sign[],char VorF[],float Spec_Minnimum,float Spec_Maximum)
{
int x;
float Act_Gap, Act_Tollerance, Maximum_Gap = 0.0, Minnimum_Gap = 0.0;
for ( x=0, Act_Gap = 0; x<size; x++){   //does tolerance math
            Act_Gap = Act_Gap + (nominal[x]*sign[x]);
}
for ( x=0, Act_Tollerance = 0; x<size; x++){
                Act_Tollerance = Act_Tollerance + (tollerance[x]);
}
for (x= 0, Maximum_Gap = 0; x<size; x++){
                Maximum_Gap = (nominal[x]*sign[x]+tollerance[x])+Maximum_Gap;
                Minnimum_Gap = (nominal[x]*sign[x]-tollerance[x])+Minnimum_Gap;
}

printf("Actual Gap Mean: %.3f\"\n", Act_Gap);  //printing
printf("Actual Gap Tolerance: %.3f\"\n", Act_Tollerance);
if (Maximum_Gap > Spec_Maximum){
    printf("The maximum gap (%.3f\") is (Greater) than specified (%.3f\")\n", Maximum_Gap, Spec_Maximum);
}
if (Maximum_Gap < Spec_Maximum){
    printf("The maximum gap (%.3f\") is (Less) than specified (%.3f\")\n", Maximum_Gap, Spec_Maximum);
}
if (Minnimum_Gap > Spec_Minnimum){
    printf("The minimum gap (%.3f\") is (Greater) than specified (%.3f\")\n", Minnimum_Gap, Spec_Minnimum);
}
if (Minnimum_Gap < Spec_Minnimum){
    printf("The minimum gap (%.3f\") is (Less) than specified (%.3f\")\n", Minnimum_Gap, Spec_Minnimum);
}
return 0;
}

float toleranceadjust(int size, float nominal[],float tollerance[], int sign[], char VorF[])
{
```

Any hints or tips would be greatly apreciated.

Comment: Sidenote: lt's `tolerance`.

Comment: Any hints or tips what your actual problem is would be greatly appreciated. A line of generic prose and 100 lines of undocumented code (full of typos...) aren't a requirement specification. Anyway, SO is about solving programming problems, not a "write my code" engine. *What have you tried?*